# How can I access contents of a SharePoint repo without downloading contents to my computer?

Tags: powershell, backup, office365, sharepoint

OK so I will probably butcher some terminology but bear with me...

Our organization in transitioning to the Microsoft infrastructure. One thing that was done was backup to SharePoint of a NAS backup drive. What I am trying to figure out is how I access the contents of that backup without having to download massive files to my computer.

For example, suppose there was a folder on the backup drive called `Foo` that had large files `bar.zip` and `baz.pptx` in it. In the past I could mount the drive as a logical drive, say `Z:`, and I could then open a console or PowerShell window and do things like `cd z:\Foo` and `dir z:\Foo\baz.zip`. Or I could open `baz.pptx` in PowerPoint without having to copy it first to my local drive `c:`

Now the folder has been copied to SharePoint. I can access the location through my browser via the right URL, but can I do operations like the above from a PowerShell window **without having to first make a local copy of the contents**? In other words, I want to explore contents of the repo using console commands and scripts rather than by clicking around in the browser.

If this can be done, is there a good guide you can recommend? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can map a SharePoint folder to a drive letter, with some preparations.

- Add your SharePoint base URL to "Trusted Sites":
  Run *Internet Options > Security tab > Trusted Sites > Sites*.
- In the Services applet, ensure that the WebClient service is running.
  You may set it to start automatically.
- You may now map a drive-letter to the SharePoint folder via Explorer's
  Map Network Drive, or using the `net use` command:

  ```
     net use T: \\poshlab2.sharepoint.com@SSL\sites\ITOps /persistent:yes
  ```

For extensive details with screenshots, see the article
[How to Map a SharePoint Drive](https://adamtheautomator.com/map-sharepoint-drive/).

Comment: When I try to map the drive following "Using Windows Explorer to Map SharePoint as Network Drive", I get `the device attached to the system is not functioning`. When I put the same URL into Edge, it opens up fine. The URL does not have the same patter as in the example. It looks like `https://BLAH.sharepoint.com/personal/BLAH/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?MORE_BLAH`. So not sure what's "site" here and what's "library"

Comment: The site is `https://BLAH.sharepoint.com`. The linked article defines it very well, follow it.

Comment: I think I have. Tried mounting it in Windows Explorer, using PowerShell and `net` and got a mix of System 59, system 67 and `A device attached to the system is not functioning` errors

Comment: Does mounting Sharepoint folders still work now that IE is no longer usable?

Comment: @Robert: `net use` will still work.

Comment: @harrymc If I do so I get the error `Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.`. Add to trusted sites is still possible but browsing to the sharepoint site using IE and save login credentials doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Robert: Internet Options is still in Windows. It's not dependent on IE.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry but I never said that IE options are the problem (I even mentioned that adding trusted sites in IE options is still possible). It is the fact that you have to open Sharepoint server in IE to save login credentials which causes the problem.

Comment: @Robert: I don't use Sharepoint, but it would astound me if after retiring IE Microsoft did not furnish an alternative method. You could post a new question about the subject.

Comment: Indeed a new question may be helpful. I have created one: https://superuser.com/questions/1733898/mounting-a-sharepoint-folder-in-windows-10-without-ie