# Mounting a SharePoint folder in Windows 10 without IE

Tags: windows-10, mount, sharepoint

There are multiple [questions](https://superuser.com/q/1664321/62676) and [tutorials](https://adamtheautomator.com/map-sharepoint-drive/) that show how to mount a Sharepoint storage directory as network drive on Windows 10. Unfortunately all ways to mount a Sharepoint storage in Windows seem to require Internet Explorer to save the used login credentials.
If you try to mount Sharepoint without saving credentials in IE you are getting an error like:

> Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.

Adding Sharepoint server to the list of trusted servers is still possible using Internet Options control panel, but IE is no longer usable (and IE mode in Edge is disabled via group policy on my system) so all those tutorials no longer work.

Is there still a possibility to mount a Sharepoint storage directory as network drive on Windows without using IE or Edge-IE mode?

Answer (score 1):

This method was found in the post
[SharePoint Drive Mapping Windows 11- Internet Explorer options locked out](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-drive-mapping-windows-11-internet-explorer-options/m-p/3033145/thread-id/55782)
and especially in the linked PDF file.

Here are the details for mapping SharePoint in Windows 11 & 10
without IE:

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to :
  *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components >
  Internet Explorer >  Internet Control Panel.
  Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer >
  Security Page*
- Double-click on "Site to Zone Assignment List"
- Check Enabled
- Click Show...

  - Set "Value name" as `https://mydomain.sharepoint.com`
  - Set "Value" as `2` for Trusted site
- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) and run the command `GPUPDATE /FORCE`
- Run Edge
- Click the 3-dots menu > Settings > Default Browser
- Set "Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode (IE mode)" to
  Allow
- Click in "Internet Explorer mode pages" the Add button
  and add your SharePoint site
- To avoid drive disconnection, run the Services applet (`services.msc`),
  and ensure that the Webclient service is running and is set to auto-start.

Comment: Sorry I am just a user without admin permissions so I don't have access to GPOs. Furthermore IE mode is disabled as I wrote in my question. Furthermore as far as I know Office365 does no longer support IE11 so Edge in IE mode should in my understanding also no longer work.

Comment: You will need to get help from an admin. If you can create a virtual machine with an earlier Windows version, you could perhaps use it for SharePoint. Note that mounting SharePoint is counted by Microsoft as deprecated. You could perhaps use OneDrive instead.

Answer (score 0):

i played with it a few days.
Even if ouy have blocked IE via GPO you can run IE using simple vbs file.
OPne notepad, paste it there and save as f.e. **LaunchIE.vbs**.
######################################################

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
oIE.Visible = True 
oIE.Navigate "about:blank"
```

######################################################

Then run it **cscript LaunchIE.vbs**

After that IE will appear and you can type your sharepoint url to browser. Dont worry if you see that IE is not supported to view this page, on backround will be created webclient connection to page. Than you can map your sharepoint as network drive.

Note: if you will still have
*Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.*

Then just logon to one drive one time. Then will be connection established and network map will working